# Having a hash map to keep track of elements in another data structure

Tags: algorithm

So sometimes I have a certain ds with certain functionalities which have a get time complexity of O(N)  like a queue, stack, heap, etc..  I use one of these ds in a program which just needs to check whether a certain element is in one of theses ds, but because they have a get complexity of O(N), it is the pitfall in my algorithm.

If memory isn't much of my worries, would it be poor design to have a hashmap which keeps track of the elements in the restricted data structure? Doing this would essentially remove the O(N) restriction and allow it to be O(1).

Comment: Just a warning, hashmaps do not have a time complexity of O(1) on the strict sense. Hash maps/tables are actually O(n). However their AMORTIZED time complexity is O(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a supplemental hash table is warranted in many situations. However, maintaining a "parallel hash" could become a liability.

The situation that you describe, when you need to check membership quickly, is often modeled with a hash-based set (`HashSet<T>`, `std::unordered_set<T>`, and so on, depending on the language). The disadvantage of these structures is that the order of elements is not specified, and that they cannot have duplicates.

Depending on the library, you may have access to data structures that fix these shortcomings. For example, Java offers `LinkedHashSet<T>` which provides a predictable order of enumeration, and C++ provides `std::unordered_multiset<T>`, which allows duplicates.